# How to make Gulp read babel.config.js of Babel7 in the root of the project?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gulp, babeljs

This is my project structure:

```
Project
|-module1
|  |-package.json
|  |-gulpfile.babel.js
|-module2
|  |-package.json
|  |-gulpfile.babel.js  
|-package.json
|-scripts.js
|-babel.config.js
```

As you see in root of the project I have `scripts.js` that exports some things. After reading all the information about Babel7 configuration     [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration) in the root of the project I created `babel.config.js` with the following content:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/env', {
      targets: {
        node: 'current',
        firefox: '60',
        chrome: '67',
        safari: '11.1',
      },
    }],
  ],
};
```

As I understand I don't need to create `.babelrc` in `module1` and `module2` as I have a `babel.config.js` in the root. However, when I run gulp on `module1` I see that gulp doesn't find the configuration for babel as I get:

```
Project/module1/gulpfile.babel.js:26
import gulp from 'gulp';
       ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found is the following - we should use `gulpfile.js` instead of `gulpfile.babel.js` and config babel manually. I mean:

in `Project/module1/gulpfile.js`

```
require('@babel/register')({
    configFile: './../babel.config.js',
    ignore: [/node_modules/]
})
require('./tasks')
```

and in `Project/module1/tasks.js` we put all gulp tasks.